# Open vSwitch double VLAN tagging is ignored

Tags: kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, vlan, openvswitch, dynamic-vlan-assignment

I'm trying to add a flow to a KVM machine using Open vSwitch 1.10.2 for it's networking, which double tag all traffic comming from one of the virtual machine's ports.
I'm using the following command to add the flow:

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 -O OpenFlow13 cookie=0xFF,priority=4,in_port=1,dl_vlan=1,ip,tcp,actions=push_vlan:0x8100,set_field:1000-\>vlan_vid,push_vlan:0x8100,set_field:1001-\>vlan_vid,NORMAL
```

the command is executed and ovs-ofctl returns 0. However, the actual flow added ignores the push vlan command and just set two set_field actions for VLAN ID, which override each other.

Any suggestions for the reason of this?

Itamar

Comment: Double VLAN ? Do you mean QinQ ? it seems it is not supported yet http://openvswitch.org/pipermail/discuss/2014-March/013346.html

Comment: I see... so is there any other way to implement double encapsulation of networks (without using any tunneling such as GRE, etc...)

Comment: Tunnels are not something to be afraid of. Even OVS makes heavy use of them.